# Elasticsearch aggregate function error on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch gives error when integrating with laravel using aggregations. This is my code:

```
        $laws_y = Law::searchByQuery([
            'multi_match' => [
                'query' => $years,
                'fields' => ["law_year"]
            ],
            "aggs" => [
                "group_by_law_year" => ["terms" => ['field' => ["law_year"]]]
            ]
        ]);
```

I get following error:

> BadRequest400Exception in GuzzleConnection.php line 277:
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to
>   parse search source. expected field name but got
>   [START_OBJECT]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
>   shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"default","node":"BcRQOVhkS1SwTlvYPCEfHg","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed
>   to parse search source. expected field name but got
>   [START_OBJECT]"}}]},"status":400}

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Elasticquent documentation](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent#searching), the `searchByQuery` function takes the following parameters (see [source here](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent/blob/b885455305bea34bb5bd922bdab0dea730def58e/src/ElasticquentTrait.php#L244)):

- `query` - Your ElasticSearch Query
- `aggregations` - The Aggregations you wish to return.
- `sourceFields` - Limits returned set to the selected fields only
- `limit` - Number of records to return
- `offset` - Sets the record offset (use for paging results)
- `sort` - Your sort query

In your call, you need to separate the query (first parameter) from the aggregations (second parameter). Do it like this instead:

```
     $laws_y = Law::searchByQuery([
        'multi_match' => [
            'query' => $years,
            'fields' => ["law_year"]
        ]
     ],
     [
        "group_by_law_year" => ["terms" => ['field' => "law_year"]]
     ]);
```

Comment: Yes that solved that error, but I still get another error

BadRequest400Exception in GuzzleConnection.php line 277:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"Could not find aggregator type [group_by_law_year] in [aggs]","line":1,"col":92}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"default","node":"BcRQOVhkS1SwTlvYPCEfHg","reason":{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"Could not find aggregator type [group_by_law_year] in [aggs]","line":1,"col":92}}]},"status":400}

Comment: Are you including the `aggs` token in your second parameter?

Comment: This is the result when I run dd($years): "2013 2012 2013 ". Can that help?

Comment: This is the mapping property:

    protected $mappingProperties = array(
        'law_year' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            "analyzer" => "standard",
        ],
    );

In the database law_year field is an integer, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: No, it's probably not the issue. Are you using the exact same code as I've written in my answer?

Comment: The code was different somehow, but now when I try your code it says:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [group_by_law_year]: [field].","line":1,"col":114}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"default","node":"BcRQOVhkS1SwTlvYPCEfHg","reason":{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [group_by_law_year]: [field].","line":1,"col":114}}]},"status":400}

Comment: Please try again, I've removed the array in the aggregation, `['field' => "law_year"]` instead of `['field' => ["law_year"]]`